# Dilate a smaill matrix 28X28 opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

I am trying to fill holes on a small matrix that represents a digit:

[image]

[image]

I tried using:

```
cv::Mat element = getStructuringElement(CV_SHAPE_ELLIPSE, cv::Size(1, 1));
dilate(srcMat, dstMat, element);
```

any size bigger then `Size(1, 1)` wont work, and we don't see any change after the dilation.

Comment: It would be great if you share some code and images that reproduces the problem. It should work, did you use 3x3, 5x5 or 7x7 kernel sizes?

Comment: How I understand doas a 1x1 matrix don't make sense. Try cv::Size(3, 3).

Comment: 1x1 Size is a void operation - it does nothing. Like multiplying by 1 or adding zero to a number. Use filter of size 3 (3x3) or larger!